# How to get an authentication provider status list from IIS (for a Sharepoint site)?

Tags: iis, authentication, python, providers, web-applications

I need to get the authentication provider status of a web application available in IIS  through C# or Python code.

Example: Is Basic Authentication available for X site?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# (.NET), you could search the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(VS.90).aspx) namespace.

The LogonMethod property of the VirtualDirectory class should contain that information. Here's a [code example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.web.administration.authenticationlogonmethod(VS.90).aspx).